# How to remove graph lines from cardiogram image, enable OCR

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr, contour

I have a document page:
[image: Document page]

I'm looking for a way to remove the straight graph lines so that I can OCR the text seen at the top/right.

I will be happy to listen any ideas! :)

Thanks!

UPDATE 2022-03-14:

I've tried to process the picture with the following code (FFT):

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('60.censored.png',0)

f1 = np.fft.fft2(img)
fshift1 = np.fft.fftshift(f1)
magnitude_spectrum1 = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift1))

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Input Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(magnitude_spectrum1, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Magnitude Spectrum'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

And now I've got the picture:
[image]

Is any idea what to do next?

Comment: somewhat common task. use a fourier transform. you'll see the grid of lines as a grid of points, which represent those strong frequencies that generate your grid of lines. find and erase those peaks. then transform back. grid should be gone. result might look weird, have some high frequency artefacts remaining. best to use high resolution scans. -- alternatively, ignore the grid, and focus on selecting what you _do_ want (the curves?) robustly. they're thicker than the grid so that should be feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! My task is text recognition (OCR). Actually, I'm looking for a way to clear the image before Tesseract. Tesseract generates a lot of trash text when it is trying to process similar pictures.

Comment: oh boy, the text there? I'm not sure how well the text is maintained through that fourier filtering stuff. might be okay, might not be. -- can you assume a single font and font size (or small set of those)? then you can gainfully train the OCR for that specific font, while _ignoring_ any annoying grid, without having to remove it. AI is good at that...

Comment: maybe you could train some convolutional neural network to remove this grid (and leave the text and curves alone). you'd need to produce a lot of training data. synthetic data should be good enough. if the network is smart, it'll learn the appearance of the text too, and implicitly do OCR... beware of the blunder that Xerox made with their copiers, which were so smart (jbig2) that they collapsed similar-looking digits into the same glyph, ruining data and engineering documents

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no assumption about the font. I realy need a general solution. But thank you for the mentioned keyword :)

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz ! I've applied the fft to the picture. I've got a 2d spectre. I've put the result to the current question. Can you help pe with the next step?

Comment: ah yes. this is "shifted" so the DC component is in the center, right? leave the DC component alone, but erase (set to 0) some of the peaks you see in the spectrum. then transform it back. the spectrum must maintain its complex numbers for this to work, i.e. don't turn it into a picture and edit that in a photo editor. you'll want to pick those points and clear those elements in the array.

Comment: demo: https://imgur.com/a/aPzJWnO (I used ImageJ for that)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, thank you so much! It is amazing!
Did you erase the peaks manually?

Comment: yes, I just used the paintbrush tool and clicked on them. this is automatable though. you're looking for local maxima (largest value in the neighborhood) and maybe only those that have a certain absolute magnitude (fixed threshold). -- if you know (measure) the "wavelength" of the grid (in pixels), you can calculate where the peaks should be, and "blindly" erase them, given some measurement from the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't expect getting high quality OCR results from such an image. Thresholding such an image will significantly affect the text. However, if you can get the images scanned in color, you may [convert colors](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html) first to avoid affecting your text.

[image]

Comment: How did you got the result? Just using thresholding? It can be a solution for my case.

Comment: It's reading the image as gray, gaussian blur, and binary threshold "cv2.threshold(blur, 130, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)."

Comment: Thank you! Gonna use it as a part of a composite solution.

Comment: That's great! You're always welcome! :)